# Route::Auth not surrounded in Middleware

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Laravel `routes.php`. So when I look at Auth examples for Laravel 5.2, I ALWAYS ALWAYS see the `Route::auth();` and `Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')` encapsulated in `{` of the `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {` thing. But whenever I use the commands `php artisan make:auth` all it does is create the one I showed above.

Any clues on why this does this? It works fine and all but I'm not 100% sure if  it's functioning properly. But I can tell you that I can login and sign-up properly. Did they do any changes to Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the web middleware is now applied by default:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/app/Http

Also in Kernel.php

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php

Comment: With regards to the confusion, the change was made after the release of Laravel 5.2, specifically in the framework version 5.2.27. This is why you are seeing lots of examples with the group.